# What is the way to update automatically, seconds in time using php code?

Tags: php

Is there any way to add php code for updating automatically the seconds in time format without  using javascript.

Thanks

Comment: No. Not really. PHP is a one time thing. `Client -> Request -> Server -> Response -> Client`. The only way would be to flush your buffer with the new time, but even so, you'd need to flush javascript code in order to update a field, and it'd just be a bad idea.

Comment: Weird question. Javascript is client-side as PHP is server-side interpreted so PHP is useless here. Or maybe I did not understand your question...

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to update a time value in rendered HTML that was produced by PHP?

The only way is to continually reload the page using some HTML reloading tag that I can't (and don't want to) remember every second to show the updated time. Don't do it please, it's annoying to users. Use JavaScript or just don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `meta` tag in html

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=your_url">
```

Comment: Gah, that's the tag I didn't want to remember. Oh the humanity I hope nobody uses that for this purpose.